# How to find out the correct packet length?

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols, tcpdump

I am sending three types of packets on another machine in LAN using **SENDIP** tool
I have specified min. length = 8 bytes and max.length = 512 bytes...

but....

when I send udp packets (min. length) and capture using **tcpdump** it shows pointer length=70 bytes.

when I send udp packets (min. length) **tcpdump** shows pointer length=574 bytes.

when I send icmp packets (min length),**tcpdump** shows length of first two packets as 80 and length of rest all packets as 66 bytes.

The pointer length I am getting through tcpdump is by using header information specified in the packet....

Why there is discrepancy between the results of sendip and tcpdump ???

Comment: I did not understand very well... Can you show us an example, with screenshot from tcpdump and your php page?

Comment: Bhai.. Not able to understand !

Comment: you listed udp twice and icmp once...is one of them supposed to be tcp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-s 0` option when running tcpdump. This will cause it to capture the entire frame.

Comment: ok .... that helped It was actually some other minute mistake which I could find out by capturing the full frame.